# Codeforces 13C Solution

Tags: c++, sorting, dynamic-programming

http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/13/C
I am having problem with the problem above. Can anyone explain the solution clearly. My code seems pretty okay to me, however it is not passing testcase 8.

```
lli n;
cin>>n;
lli arr[size];
fi(i,n)
cin>>arr[i];
if(n==1)
    cout<<"0"<<endl;
else
{
    lli sum=0;
    for(lli i=n-1; i>0; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i]<arr[i-1])
        {
            lli k=abs(arr[i]-arr[i-1]);
            if(i==(n-1))
            {
                arr[i]+=k;
                sum+=k;
            }
            else
            {
                if((arr[i]+k)<=arr[i+1])
                    arr[i]+=k, sum+=k;
                else
                    arr[i-1]-=k, sum+=k;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: what is test case 8?

Comment: `5000
960440941 -427665346 366632330 -922577959 -708929687 592187815 -119993724 -818916365 -808029838 306092723 916069264 -21931800 609160933 -699461833 -978359151 629415472 -354990986 -965311699 -137369406 -583707511 -948526279 867343453 -421546982 -2873...`             http://codeforces.com/problemset/status/13/problem/C

Comment: what is the max value of lli type? is it 32 bit or 64 bit ?

Comment: I typeded lli to `long long int` and ran your program. In my ubuntu machine long long int is 64 bits. So, I got the right answer of 18203564911. I also printed the value of sum and k at each iteration and it matched. I don't see any issues with your code if you have used the right type for lli (i.e, it should not overflow).

Comment: The correct answer is 2527130128540. See in link provided in comment. I was also getting the same output. I can't think of any problem..

Comment: I tried for the data:
5000 960440941 -427665346 366632330 -922577959 -708929687 592187815 -119993724 -818916365 -808029838 306092723 916069264 -21931800 609160933 -699461833 -978359151 629415472 -354990986 -965311699 -137369406 -583707511 -948526279 867343453 -421546982 -2873

Comment: the link does not show what you want to intend to show. For me it shows only the status of people whose code was accepted.

Comment: ok, saw the answer in the link.

Comment: the first number 5000 represents number of elements in the sequence. So, the input sequence should have 5000 elements. Whatever I tried your code was for only those 25 elements you pasted. I think you have missed the input. Otherwise, I don't see any problem with your code. Hope you got the problem. In http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/13/C, it is clearly mentioned that the first number is N (1 <= N <= 5000) is the number of elements in sequence. the following elements are actual elements in sequence. So, you need to have 5000 elems. I tried only for 25 typed by you.

Comment: Okay Thanks..Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The program compares if `arr[i]` is less than `arr[i-1]`, this may fail in case like `10000 1 1 1`.

The solution that is O(n) it would be making the average and the change every number to the average number.